# flask - Get query result for session

Tags: python, mysql, flask

In my table users have roles like admin/client. https://i.stack.imgur.com/71yfO.jpg and i want to display their role in html tag

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "mysecretkey"
app.config["MYSQL_HOST"] = "localhost"
app.config["MYSQL_USER"] = "root"
app.config["MYSQL_PASSWORD"] = ""
app.config["MYSQL_DB"] = "blog"
app.config["MYSQL_CURSORCLASS"] = "DictCursor"
mysql = MySQL(app)

class LoginForm(Form):
    username = StringField("Username:")
    password = PasswordField("Password:")


@app.route("/login", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    form = LoginForm(request.form)

    if request.method == "POST":
        username = form.username.data
        password_entered = form.password.data

        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
        sorgu = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s AND role = %s"
        result = cursor.execute(sorgu, (username,role))

        if result > 0:
            data = cursor.fetchone()
            real_password = data["password"]

            role = cursor.fetchone()
            user_role = role["role"]



            if sha256_crypt.verify(password_entered, real_password):
                flash("successfully logged in", "success")

                session["logged_in"] = True
                session["username"] = username
                session["role"] = role



                return redirect(url_for("index"))

            else:
                flash("wrong password", "danger")
                return redirect(url_for("login"))

        else:
            flash("there is no user", "danger")
            return redirect(url_for("login"))

    return render_template("login.html", form=form)
```

and i want to display role in my dashboard.html like this;

```
<small>Welcome {{session["username"]}}</small>
<small>Role: {{session["role"]}}</small>
```

When im trying to login, this is what i get: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'role' referenced before assignment"

Answer (score 0):

You are using the variable `role` before assigning any value to it in:

```
        sorgu = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s AND role = %s"
        result = cursor.execute(sorgu, (username,role))
```

I guess what you want to do is just:

```
        sorgu = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s"
        result = cursor.execute(sorgu, (username,))
```

Comment: Actually i know this mistake. The problem is i don't know how to get role from my database and how can i add it in session. I need the display role like username in dashboard.html

Comment: If you change the code as the way I posted above, will there be any error? If yes, what is the error?

Comment: after a couple hour sleep. i solved. i can't believe how didn't i think of it

Comment: i wrote in comments